# bad include syntax Error in minix

Tags: c, unix, minix

```
#include <lib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int mq_close(int queue)
{
    message m;
    m.m3_i1= queue;
    return (_syscall(PM_PROC_NR,MQ_CLOSE,&m));
}
```

While I am updating my libraries in minix I am getting this error "bad include syntax error".. Help me out in this.

Comment: Where is your `main()` function? Did you eat it?

Comment: Please show the exact error message, with file names, line numbers and all, indented as code. Apparently, the message is "bad include syntax error", but what you show is the correct syntax. So, either the error message is incorrectly quoted or it does not apply to the code you show but rather to something in one of the headers you include. My money would be on "problem in `<lib.h>`", assuming that is your header rather than a system header. As a general rule, put system headers in angle brackets (`<stdio.h>`); put other headers in quotes (`"header.h"`).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
#include <lib.h>
```

into

```
#include <minix/lib.h>
```

Assuming you installed minix using the  [guide.](http://wiki.minix3.org/en/UsersGuide/DoingInstallation)